# how templates work on wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, web-applications

Does any have the idea of how wordpress works.
I am very much curious about to know the working and flow of execution in wordpress.
How they are managing the templates and htaccess controll follow etc.

Help me and share your knowledge with me.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some frameworks to get you started:

[Wordpress Theme Frameworks explained](http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/wordpress-theme-frameworks)

Answer (score 2):

There are two things that really helped me out.

First, get familiar with the default template.  Try changing some of the PHP files in the wp-content/ folder.

Second, when you feel like you understand the basics of what is going on, go through some of the Wordpress tutorials.  They are informative and helpful.

A nice intro.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Stepping_Into_Templates

Answer (score 0):

I'd also recommend taking a look through the database. Log into PHPMyAdmin or something similar, and look at what's being saved where, and what it's being called. It clicked for me when I saw the column names later in WP tags that called "blog_description" or whatever, and I knew what it was calling.

And beyond the codex, you can actually dig around in the "real" PHP that drives the engine and not the "pseudo" PHP that comprises WP-Tags etc.

Answer (score 0):

Start with the template hierarchy diagram:
(Visual Overview section)
http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy

Then read the relevant PHP file to see what's happening depending on which page is being displayed.

Answer (score 0):

If you like screen casts, WordPress TV has a walkthrough of the anatomy of a WordPress theme which might be helpful: 
http://wordpress.tv/2009/03/16/anatomy-of-a-wordpress-theme-exploring-the-files-behind-your-theme/